# how to redraw the datatable with the same parameter but start and length should be increase like when change paging and start and length changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How to redraw the datatable with the same parameter but start and length should be increase like when change paging and start and length changes

```
var start = 0; // Initialize start parameter
var length = 10;
itemTabel = $('#reciept-table').DataTable({
       processing : true,
       serverSide : true,
       searching : true,
       dom:'Bltrip',
       buttons: [
         {
           extend: 'excel',
           action: newexportaction
         },
         {
           extend: 'print',
           action: newexportaction
         }
       ],
       _iDisplaylength:20,

       language: {
               lengthMenu: "Show _MENU_ rows",
               info: "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ rows"
           },
           columnDefs: [{
                   orderable: false,
                   targets: [0]
               },
               {
                   orderable: true,
                   targets: '_all'
               }
           ],
          responsive: true,
          ajax:{
           url : "<?= base_url('Order/ViewGenerateReceipt_item')?>",
           type : "POST",
           data : {
               customer,date,to_date,status,is_report
            },
           
          select: {
            style: 'multi'
          },

          drawCallback:function(settings,data)
           {

                var api = this.api();
                var data = api.rows().data();
                console.log(data.length)
              if (data.length === 0) {
                   // Current draw data is empty, increment start and length
                    data.start = length;
                    data.length = length;
                   // Redraw the datatable with the updated parameters
                   //itemTabel.draw()
                }
               

               $('#tot_weight').html(settings.json.tot_weight.toFixed(3));
               $('#tot_fine').html(settings.json.tot_fine.toFixed(3));
               $('#tot_wfine').html(settings.json.tot_wfine.toFixed(3));
           },
           rowCallback: function(row, data) {
            if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selectedProductId) !== -1) {
              $(row).addClass('selected');
              $('#select-all').prop('checked', true)
            } else {
              $('#select-all').prop('checked', false)
            }
          },
          
          length += 10;
        });`
```

I am trying to redraw the table in data length is 0 and the start and length parameter value will change for next draw of table